# Inconsistent answers with conditional expectations

Tags: uniform-distribution, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables distributed uniformly on $[0,1]$.
I want to compute:

$$E[X+Y\mid\max\{X,Y\}≤(1/2)]$$

My first approach was the following. Let $X=\max\{X,Y\}$. Then I know that $$E[X \mid X \leq 1/2]=1/3 \quad  \text{and}  \quad E[Y \mid Y<X\leq1/2]=1/6$$ and hence

$$E[X+Y \mid \max\{X,Y\} \leq 1/2]=1/2$$

But then I thought: doesn't $\max\{X,Y\} \leq 1/2$ also imply that $X+Y$ must be less or equal than 1? Since $X+Y$ follows a triangular distribution, we can compute the expected value of $X+Y$ conditional on it not exceeding $1$. If we do so, what we get is

$$E[X+Y \mid X+Y\leq 1]=2/3$$

But why do I get two different answers?

Comment: Yes $\max \{X,Y\}\leq 1/2$ does imply that $X+Y<1$ but the opposite direction is not true, i.e. $X+Y<1$ does not imply that $\max \{X,Y\}\leq 1/2$, so the two statements are not equivalent. This means in particular that you cannot substitute the former statement with the latter in the conditional.

Comment: Thanks!
Therefore, can I conclude that the right answer to the original question (the one with the max) is indeed 1/2?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.